# Mixing Corsair Vengeance Ram at 1600mhz with 2133mhz ? Issues?

Tags: memory

So I have 2x4 Gb of Corsair Vengeance Ram running at 1600mhz, I was going to buy at additional 2x4gb of corsair vengeance ram but at 2133mhz as I'm getting it at a good price and was wondering if I would have any issues ?

My mobo is Gigabyte ga-z68-ud5-b3 so it's a decent enough one. 
I'm running Windows 8.1

Comment: There should be no issues.  The faster memory will automatically be clocked at the slower frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your computer supports the RAM, the only complication would be that your new RAM will not be running at full speed, but instead running at the highest common speed that both sets support.